# How to find 'n' raise to power 'n' in java

Tags: java

I am trying to find an efficient way for calculating **N^N** in java. As the result will be very large for large N, I used BigInteger as my result data type and N is integer. If N becomes large say **N=10000000** then it **takes more time** to calculate the result. Is there any efficient way that will calculate it within a second.

Comment: I doubt it. That is a pretty big number.

Comment: No, check the result [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10000000%5E10000000) that's a lot of digits

Comment: @RC The computation actually times out (which makes sense. That is a *crazy* big number.)

Comment: @dev, I know, I thought the number of digits + timeout was relevant

Comment: Do you really need that number? The whole number? Because it's unlikely that you need a 70 million digit number (in decimal) every second. If you only need parts of it, say, the first few digits, there are ways to help you.

Comment: You could use BigInteger.pow(int) to meet your requirements. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#pow(int)

Comment: @JamesB:  No.  You *can't*.  That's the *problem*.

Comment: 70 million decimal digits is less then 35 MB, it can be possible.

Comment: Go buy a supercomputer!

Comment: @JamesB : yeah, I already used BigInteger.pow(int) function but it takes more time to calculate the value.

Comment: @zch Sure it's possible, and not too hard, but not trivial to do in under a second. I'm still on the "this is not really what the OP **needs**" train.

Comment: @Carsten: If there is any way to find out most of the digit, say first few or few last digit, then please help me out.

Comment: It takes "more time" by necessity, yet maybe with another BigInt library you're a bit better off.

Comment: I would try `(5**70M) << 70M`.

Comment: @PrathameshRaut I'd love to. But then please specify what you need. Really, all 70 million digits? What would you define as "most" of them? Or first few or last? If you describe what you want to do, this will become easier, because we can simplify your problem with the help of Math (TM).

Comment: @Carsten In the example, it is too easy: the first digit will be 1 and the rest 0. But how about 23456789 ^ 23456789

Comment: @Carsten : ok , suppose I have the value N=10000000,then I want the first and last K digit of N^N.

Comment: @PrathameshRaut This is easily told, as long as K is lower than 70 million. `first(K, 10000000^10000000) = 1 followed by (K-1) 0` and `last(K, 10000000^10000000) = K zeroes`

Comment: @Ingo: Its right for N=10000000 but how will you define it for any N say N = 23456789

Comment: This seems to require a longer discussion. Can we please [continue it in the chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139/java)?

Comment: @Carsten : I dont know whats the problem but i am unable to chat as they keep on telling, that you need 20 reputation, even if i have it.

Comment: You now have > 20 reputation.  You may now go to chat.

Comment: @Makoto Already upvoted him to >20 15 minutes ago. Yet, he doesn't seem to want to answer.

Comment: @Carsten : Now chat window is functioning properly, i tried a lot but didn't resolved it. I searched for the problem and found that StackOverflow taking more time to refresh reputation points.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Handle the log of the number, which is `N ln(N)`, in your program. As `N` grows, the size of `N ln(N)` relative to `N^N` shrinks faster and faster.

The way you would implement this depends on what you need to do. If you don’t need your `N^N` inside the program, then just forget about it and do it on paper once the program outputs. When you’re handling numbers that big, its log/order of magnitude/the number of digits it has (all of those are synonymous) is most of the essential information. If your program outputs `x`, you would report that the answer is around `e^x`, and that would be about all you could say.

If you do need `N^N` inside your program, then you should still calculate `x = ln(N^N) = N ln(N)`. But then you’re going to have to come up with some creative way of going from `x` to some value that your program can actually use.

Comment: Pretty solid answer.  Only taking what you care about, leaving the rest behind.